# What is this reference material in spectrophotometry?

Tags: spectroscopy, spectrophotometry

First, I should say I never have done any spectroscopies and I am just reading about it.

As far as I know, UV-Vis spectrophotometer has 2 beam samples: **sample** and **reference**. The sample has very diluted test material in a solvent and the reference is only the solvent.

I was reading a book about some experimental values for UV-Vis spectrophotometry and I noticed this page.  My question is about that sentence saying **"The data were obtained .. against water reference"** .   As the reference is the solvent alone, ***does it mean the samples are dilute solutions in water*** ?  if so, how they solved benzene in water?

Here is a snapshot of the text:

[image]

Comment: Our UV-Vis is a single beam instrument. It does not require a pair of matched cuvettes since it records the reference spectrum to subtract from the sample spectrum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As the reference is the solvent alone, does it mean the samples are dilute solutions in water ? if so, how they solved benzene in water?

I come to a different conclusion.

To me it reads as follows:

- sample: **solution** of benzene, acetone, acetonitrile, etc. **in** water
- reference: water

Benzene is soluble in water: about $1.8\,\mathrm{g\cdot L^{-1}}$ at 25 °C.

**Edit**

As a reference (blank), a solution of **everything except the sample** is used. In organic (photo)chemistry this usually means: just the solvent. The situation is different in biochemistry, medicinal chemistry, etc. when complex aqueous buffer systems are used. Here, **everything except the probe** really means that the whole buffer is used as a blank.

Comment: Thanks.  Can we say that reference and solvent are always the same ?

Comment: @Aug Mostly, but not always. I've updated my answer.